# Sealevel Pressure and Temperature Calculation

Tags: temperature, altitude

I want to know if there is any online API for getting pressure and temperature of a location. If not, then I have height above Sealevel (in meters and feet), how can I calculate that to get pressure and temperature of a location?

Comment: Pressure and temperature at a location is called "weather".  National weather services provide this information.  Are you looking for something different than the local weather?  If so, what?

Comment: as long as i can get the values for a location, i dont mind where it is from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current air pressure for a point is not a simple relationship between temperature and elevation. For a better understanding of air pressure see NOAA's brief tutorial on [Air Pressure](http://www.srh.weather.gov/jetstream/atmos/pressure.htm).

Do you want current [atmospheric pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure) for a weather station (surface level)? Do you want local [altimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altimeter) (or pressure altitude) settings for various airports and locations?

I'm assuming you are asking for current (present) conditions, not forecast data.

Your question is vague, so without knowing how you wish to use the data I cannot infer more. I hope this helps point you in the right direction, or at least helps you better understand what you really want. Good luck.

Comment: well im trying to google api and whenever user click on map, it will get sealevel and atmospheric pressure.

im not sure which api to use, cause google dont provide pressure, yahoo does, but you cant access there api, unless you know woid (location id), cant use google map to get location id for yahoo api. other api has some restrictions too, do you know any api, where i can just pass coordinates and it will give me pressure and temperatures?

Comment: I don't believe you will find anyone that gives atmospheric pressure or pressure altitude (altimeter / altimeter setting) for an arbitrary point (i.e. latitude, longitude). I think that is what you are asking for.

Comment: here i found one after lots of searching http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx, they give it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't know if there is a free (as in beer) public API but there are many weather services that provides this data for a fee.
2. Temperature and atmospheric pressure depends on the weather system, not on height, so you cannot calculate it with only "height above sealevel".

**Edit:**
Apparently Yahoo has a [public API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) that includes both Temperature and Pressure.

Comment: about your point 2: you can use a model like "International Standard Atmosphere" or "ICAO Standard Atmosphere", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

for a model of atmosphere see "International Standard Atmosphere" or "ICAO Standard Atmosphere"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere

Answer (score 0):

A web API to the NOAA/SWPC Whole Atmosphere Model Forecast System (WFS) is available here (for the temperature): https://www.amentum.io/atmosphere_docs#tag/wam-ipe