# Android get exact height above NN

Tags: android, gps, location, height

How do i get the actual (accurate ~1m) height of my location?

Ive tried registering a LocationListener, receiving the Altitude, but that does not work fine or even accurate. Im around 400m above NN and it displays 7m.

As result: GPS is not a good height-provider as i assume.

Do you have any ideas how to obtain this height?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you requested a LocationManager, not a LocationListener, and getAltitude() to obtain your height.

GPS/GNSS is not as good at altitude as it is at longitude and latitude, but for a reasonable fix you should be within 10m of the correct altitude. Note that altitude is adjusted for the geoid ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid ) and the datum ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datum_(geodesy) ) in use, which can alter your reported height compared to what you are expecting.

But you may be getting your location provided by a location provider that isn't actually GPS - it could be cell tower based, or due to dead reckoning or WiFi locationing. Or perhaps the android phone you are using just has a bad GPS integreation design that is messing with your accuracy.

I would recommend downloading a test application such as GPS Test ( see https://market.android.com/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest&hl=en ) which will show you if you have a fix, and what altitude is actually being reported by your GPS. The third box on the bottom of the GPS Test app shows altitude, heading and velocity values for each fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GPS, barometer, and data connection, you can send the GPS location to one of several weather APIs to get the local barometer setting (p0). If p1 is the value from the pressure sensor then `SensorManager.getAltitude(p0, p1)` will give you a very accurate altitude.

I don't think the altitude will have 1 meter accuracy, but it is about as accurate as you can hope for.

This SO question/answer discuses weather APIs:
[Sealevel Pressure and Temperature Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222493/sealevel-pressure-and-temperature-calculation)